# How do I stop the Phantom Emails from my PHP code?

Tags: php, html, email, verification

I'm currently using an html5 website with a contact form and a php action to receive contact emails. I've tried a few different codes in my php but non have stopped the blank emails from coming. I do have google analytics enables on my code but have blocked the crawler through robot.txt. Here is my code.

PHP CODE

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET as $Field=>$Value) { 
if($Value != ''){
$body .= "$Field: $Value\n";
}
}
$name = trim(htmlentities($_GET['name'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8'));

$email = trim(htmlentities($_GET['email'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8'));

$phone = trim(htmlentities($_GET['phone'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8'));

$messages = trim(htmlentities($_REQUEST['messages'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8'));


if (strlen($name) == 0 )
{
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.mason372.org/error.html'</script>";
}

if (strlen($email) == 0 )
{
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.mason372.org/error.html'</script>";
}


$to = "junior.8791@gmail.com";

$message = "Name: ".$name;

$message.="\n\nEmail: ".$email;

$message.="\n\nPhone: ".$phone;

$message .= "\n\nMessage: ".$messages;

$headers = "From: $email";

$headers .="\nReply-To: $email";

$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


if ($success) {

    echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.mason372.org/thankyou.html'</script>";

} else {

    echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.mason372.org/error.html'</script>";

}

?>
```

CONTACT FORM

```
 <form action="email.php" method="post" id="form">
            <div class="5grid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="6u">
                  <input type="text" class="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="" aria-describedby="name-format" required aria-required=”true” pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+"  title="e.g.'John Doe'" required="" />

                </div>
                <div class="6u">
                  <input type="email" class="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="" />

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                  <input type="tel" class="tel" name="phone" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" pattern="(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}" required />

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                  <textarea name="messages" id="messages" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message">
                  <input type="reset" class="button button-alt" value="Clear Form">
```

Comment: a bot will not be redirected by your error checking as you use js (which nost bots wont run), if you  used php this would probably fix the issue

Comment: How about you only call mail if validation passes on all of your strings? (I.e., All of the strings you care about have non-zero length, etc).

Comment: Okay is there any way @Dagon that you can guide me down the right direction, im new to coding with php. I've also been told that their are security flaws with my code. Any suggestions on what my code should look like?